# Metasploit handler failed to bind to port 4444

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, portforwarding

I am running Kali Linux on VMware. The host operating system is windows 7, and I'm using NAT for connectivity.

In my metasploit console, when I typed 'exploit' at the msf prompt,(where I am using windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp as the payload) it showed me the error

> Handler failed to bind to  **My IP:4444**

(**My IP** is my external IP address.)

So in the VMware virtual network editor, I have port forwarded port 4444 of host PC to port 4444 of the virtual PC. Then I allowed inbound packets in the firewall of the host PC, for port 4444 of the host PC.

To ensure that everything is alright, I set up an apache server on the virtual PC, that serves a webpage when accessed via port 4444. The server served flawlessly when I accessed it with an external browser. Satisfied, I shut down the server.

But guess what? Metasploit console has thrown up the same error when I typed 'exploit' again in the msf prompt.

What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

What did it say the reason for failing was.

I'm assuming the full error was failed to bind to port 4444 port is already in use.

You can not run a server on the same port you are trying to bind to.

The correct way to do this is to port forward through your router. Open your router settings and port forward port 4444 to your machines local ip.